# не работает функция с встроенной кнопкой

Tags: python, sqlite

Создаю чат-бота для учета финансов, у меня есть функция выведения траты за определенный месяц. Она работает в 2 шага: сначала пользователь нажимает на встроенную клавиатуру, ему выводит сообщение со встроенными кнопками, с помощью которых делается вывод суммы трат за определенный выбранный месяц (фото приложено).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Также из фото видно, что при нажатии на встроенную клавиатуру выводит сообщение, что трат не было, хотя траты были внесены
код, реагирующий на нажатие встроенной кнопки:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data.startswith('mstats'))
async def choose_month_stats(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    year_month = str(callback_query.data[6:])
    user_id = callback_query.id
    stats_str = expenses.get_month_stats(user_id, year_month)
    month_name = expenses.month_name(year_month)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id,
                           text(bold("Расходы за выбранный месяц\n{0}\n\n"
                                     .format(month_name))) +
                           stats_str,
                           parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)

def get_month_stats(user_id: int, year_month: str) -> str:
    print(user_id)
    cursor = db.get_cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT SUM(amount)"
        "FROM expenses "
        "WHERE STRFTIME('%Y-%m', created) = ? AND user_id = ?",
        (year_month, user_id)
    )
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(result)
    if not result[0]:
        return "В этом месяце ещё не было расходов."
    all_month_expenses = result[0]
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM expenses WHERE user_id = ?",
        (user_id,)
    )
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(user_id)
    return f"Всего потрачено: {all_month_expenses}\n"
```

Суть в том, что выводит нет трат, хотя траты в базу данных были занесены. Делала принты, при нажатии на встроенную кнопку выводит 19 цифр, что очевидно не `user_id` пользователя, поэтому выводит 0 значений, так вот вопрос: **откуда берутся эти 19 цифр**? Из-за этого встроенная кнопка работает неверно.
Надеюсь я понятно объяснила свою проблему. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: А не пробовали `callback_query.from_user.id` в качестве `user_id`? И вообще, в базу то как `user_id` попал, что вы туда писали в качестве `user_id`?

Comment: @CrazyElf дополнила

Comment: Ну вот у вас там `message.from_user.id` записывается

Comment: @CrazyElf да, заменила на callback_query.from_user.id и все получилось! Спасибо вам)